# Overwriting the Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add::getBackUrl with Plugin

Tags: magento2, plugin

I've been trying to overwrite the getBackUrl method in the Cart Add controller of the checkout. With a preference I managed without an issue but plugins are a bit more of a challenge.

Here's what I have so far.

`di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add">
        <plugin name="[namespace]_[module]_checkout_controller_cart_add_before" type="[Namespace]\[Module]\Controller\Checkout\Cart\Plugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

`Controller/Checkout/Cart/Plugin.php`

```
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Controller\Checkout\Cart;

class Plugin
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_config;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Url
     */
    protected $_url;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Url $url
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        \Magento\Framework\Url $url
    ) {
        $this->_config = $config;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }

    /**
     * Get resolved back url, rewritten to return checkout URL instead of cart url
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject
     * @return string
     */
    protected function beforeGetBackUrl(\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject)
    {
        return $this->_url->getUrl('some/custom/url');
    }
}
```

Whatever I try I can't get it to reach the `beforeGetBackUrl` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to plug in to the public non-static methods only: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#plugin-limit
It is impossible to plug in to the `protected`, `private`, `static` methods.
Also it is impossible to plug in to the public `__construct` method (constructor).
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2265 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2367 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2202#issuecomment-151599087

Comment: Wow, how did I not catch that. So in this case I should use a preference?

Comment: Preference is evil because you break all other extensions who will try to set a preference for the same class: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2443

Comment: Which I understand but in this case I don't see another option if I want to rewrite that method

Comment: You need to choose carefully  another method to plug in, or handle an event, or report the issue in the official tracker: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2265#issuecomment-154910716

Comment: already went for `execute` :) kinda weird tho, there is a perfect option but is way to limited and an 'evil' option which they shouldn't even have provided imo. 

Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot plugginize getBackUrl, but you can getUrl.

For this you need:

1. Create virtual type myUrlBulder from \Magento\Framework\Url
2. Use it as argument for \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add
3. Declare plugin for myUrlBulder virtual type

Comment: Awesome word: `plugginize`! So I ended up plugginizing the `execute` method, sounds easier but I'll try out your method as training

Comment: @KAndy:- please see my post where i added virtual type approach but not working please review my code and correct me where i missed

Comment: @KAndy:- can you post the code how to do it in virtual type i create one more question  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91353/how-to-override-the-magento-checkout-controller-cart-addgetbackurl-with-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Can I pluginize execute method or any solution to over ride the execute method of Add.php in cart controllers.

Here is the link of thread I already created few days before but no solution

[Overriding Magento 2.3 Checkout Cart Control Using Plugin using around but not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311273/overriding-magento-2-3-checkout-cart-control-using-plugin-using-around-but-not-w)

[Overriding add cart controller in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312293/overriding-add-cart-controller-in-magento-2)

Any solution any reference which can work  execute will be appreciated

Thanks