# Rewriting Magento 2 classes vs Plugins

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin

Magento 2 has the concept of [Plugins/Interception/Interceptors](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) opposed to Magento 1.
These act like a before|after the event for every public method. Which is nice.
You can also use the `around` plugin in order to replace the functionality of a method.
But Magento 2 still offers the possibility of rewrite classes more or less the M1 way.
**I would like to see some examples where rewriting classes are the way to go instead of using plugins.**
I know this is useful when you want to change the behavior of a core protected method, but are there other cases where a rewrite is recommended or needed?

Comment: Related: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93932/magento-2-plugin-vs-observer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The obvious reason to use a rewrite instead of a plugin is when you need to override a **private, protected or final methods**.

But also consider the following scenarios.

**1st scenario (absolute sort order):**

Rewrites can be useful when you need your code to be **run before plugins**.
I know you can do it by setting the plugin `sortOrder`, but you cannot be sure your code will always be the first when someone (not you) is going to install 3rd party components.

**2nd scenario (exclude code):**

If you need to exclude or **rewrite just a piece of code** in a method, a plugin could be a sub-optimal way.
I know you can use an `around` plugin and avoid calling the `proceed`, but this could break other plugins in the stack.

**3rd scenario (code style):**

You should use rewrites when you need to **rewrite** a behaviour, plugins should be used to **modify the output** or run code before/after.

A plugin, **should always run the original code** to avoid breaking other modules.

**My conclusion:**

If you can consider a core method as a **black box** with an input and one output and you are agnostic about its internal mechanisms, then a plugin could be the best option.

If you need to **change an internal behavior**, a rewrite could be the best option.

Comment: 1st scenario is slightly inaccurate (I think it's only the wording) since a before or arround plugin runs (or can run) before the actual method code.

Comment: Yes, my wording was not correct. My point was about the relative sort order with the actual method.

Answer (score 8):

Great question, I asked myself the same thing the other day and here's what I came up with:

- First, **plugins cannot be used for final methods, final classes and classes created without dependency injection** I reckon that's a very specific case but that's one case where you can't use plugins
- Second, you need to keep in mind the definition of a plugin. **It is used to work on a method level whereas preferences are used to work on the whole class level.** It is not obvious for everyone so it's good to keep that in mind.
- Finally, and I reckon that's the most important, it seems like **plugins can only be used to extend the behavior of any public method within a Magento class**. Thus it seems like you *cannot use plugins with protected/private methods*.

Source: *Magento U Fundamental Course*

Comment: Ok. Good reasons. I don't know what to say about the second point though. If you want to pluginize a lot of public methods from the same class, I think the safest way is to create a single class that acts as a plugin for all of them. (my opinion). I will leave this open 2-3 days to see if someone comes up with other reasons. If not....the checkmark is yours.

Comment: @Marius you're absolutely right re: second point. For some reasons I thought you had to create several plugin files for every method you wanted to pluginize but I think that's what observers do, not plugins. That'd be cool if more people reply to see if there's more reasons (non obvious).

Comment: @marius as an addition: as Plugins should be Domain specific, I think it should be at least best practice to only define multiple plugins in one class, if they are an implementation of the same feature. With a rewrite, you don't have this option as you always change a whole class. So I think that would be one reason to at least try to avoid rewrites

Comment: @DavidVerholen. I totally agree. But I was asking for reasons to use rewrites instead of plugins.

Comment: yes I think this could be a reason to use plugins since you can define feature specific plugin classes, while a rewrite can only be done once

Comment: so I think very superficially spoken it would be plugins for extending functionality and rewrites for changing functionality