# Magento 2 - It is posible to plug-in into a _construct method?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, plugin

It is possible?

## di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote">
        <plugin name="Vendor_Module::plugin_new" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\New" sortOrder="1" disabled="true"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

## New.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class New{
    public function before_construct(ChildBefore $subject, $interceptedInput)
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($subject);
        var_dump($interceptedInput);
        echo '</pre>';

        return ["(before) $interceptedInput (/before)"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately you can't. To overwrite `_construct` function, you have to use preference:

```
<preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote" type="Vendor\Module\Other\New" />
```

**New.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Other;

class New extends Magento\SalesRule\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        [Your code here]
        echo '</pre>';

        return parent::_construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if a want to add a new button to that block-container Magento\SalesRule\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote, how do i do it? Do i have to use preference by force?

Comment: Exactly, I don't think there is better option than preference.

Comment: No. For your particular problem, you can still use plugins. You just have to dig a little more: https://gist.github.com/adragus-inviqa/52faeb070b8f95f5f295820ddee2b406. Stop rewriting classes! There's TONS of ways to get your code in there.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately plugins can **only be used to to extend the behavior of any public method within a Magento class**. Thus, they cannot be used to extend protected/private methods such as the `_construct()` method.

In order to modify those protected/private methods you will have to **use preferences**.

If you want to find out when and when not to use plugins I suggest you have a look at this great post: [Rewriting Magento 2 classes vs Plugins](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112749/rewriting-magento-2-classes-vs-plugins)