# Are we forced to rewrite a template in Magento2 when rewritting a block?

Tags: magento2, overrides

This question is about following Magento2 best practices.

I had to rewrite \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu::_addSubMenu() method in order to add some wrappers around  elements. Now, because it's a protected method, my understanding is that I have to use preference feature:

```
<preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="MyCompany\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
```

and add a class with my rewrites:

```
<?php

namespace MyCompany\Theme\Block\Html;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{
    protected function _addSubMenu($child, $childLevel, $childrenWrapClass, $limit)
    {
        // my stuff
    }
}
```

Although the default class got rewritten, on the next page reload I got the following error:

> main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'html/topmenu.phtml' in module: 'MyCompany_Theme' block's name: 'catalog.topnav' [] []

Magento is trying to find html/topmenu.phtml under my extension and not under Magento_Theme. I do understand that this is correct behaviour, but I was thinking about practical aspects of this. Does this mean that whenever we rewrite a block, we need to rewrite its template too, even if we don't necessarily need to touch anything HTML related?

One way around this would be to rewrite _toHtml() method too, like this:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu'));
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

Now, Magento is looking into Magento_Theme module for the template file again. But, this looks like a hack to me.

So, my question is: what is a recommendation in this situations? Should we always copy relevant template when rewritting block class, or the workaround is fine? Is there a better approach for this?

Comment: Don't have time to answer right now but i suggest you have a look at this question and the answers it might help you understand the concept: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/112749/2380

Comment: interesting. The template could still be loaded from the original module if it would haven been prefixed with `Magento_Theme::`, but they did not https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml#L69 I really wonder now if this was on purpose

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Thanks. The thread you linked is about plugins. My scenario is different.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up finding once I understood what your problem was. Definitely not right sounds like a bug to me

Comment: I've created an issue on GitHub addressing this problem: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4564 waiting for an answer from the dev team and will make a PR if it ends up being a bug.

Comment: BTW, here's a PR that fixes the issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/1895/files

Answer (score 4):

Since there are discussions around the proposed solution in pull request (https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/1895), meanwhile you just need to "pin" original template when do change of original block class name:

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" class="***" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml"/>
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, although for certain blocks it would be impractical at best since it's used in so many layouts  (`Catalog\Block\Product\View`). I think the OP's suggestion is still the best solution for that instance.

Answer (score 3):

you just need to add one code in this file

```
app/design/frontend/chop/misty/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

with:

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" class="Company_name\Override\Block\Html\Topmenu" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml"/>
```

and add below code in your override module
file name :

```
app/code/Aims/Override/etc/di.xml
```

code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Company_name\Override\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
    <preference for="Magento\Paypal\Model\Config" type="Company_name\Override\Model\Paypal\Config" />
</config>
```

Add `Topmenu.php` file in 
File : `app/code/Company_name/Override/Block/Html/Topmenu.php` 
you can add whatever function you want to override.

Thanks