# Set custom price of product when adding to cart code not working

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I have write module for set custom price of product when adding to cart but my code not working.

```
     namespace Navin\Testcart\Observer;

        use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

        class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
        {
            public function invoke(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
                //echo "test";exit();
                 $item=$observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
                 $product=$observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
                $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
                // Load the custom price
                $price = $product->getPrice()+10; // 10 is custom price. It will increase in product price.
                // Set the custom price
                $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                // Enable super mode on the product.
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            }

        }
```

Help for resolve my issue.

Comment: Please add more details about your issue? Which event you want to catch?

Comment: Did you found solution??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use this even **checkout_cart_product_add_after**, and also I suggest you that

> **ObserverInterface** has only one method which is **execute**, so write your code in this method.

And do not use parent Item because while you are adding to cart any item then price depend upon child item so the best way is to use directly that item object that you are getting. So best practice is to use that item itself.

And also **return $this** object at the end of your code inside **execute** method.

> For eg:
>   namespace Navin\Testcart\Observer;

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        $item=$observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $product=$observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
        // here i am using item's product final price
        $price = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice()+10; // 10 is custom price. It will increase in product price.
        // Set the custom price
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        // Enable super mode on the product.
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: not working i have try @Rose Hale

Comment: When i apply wrong coupon code product price become 0 in row total. If i apply again, price display correct. Do you know why this happen? It happen only first time.

Comment: This is not work if when bundle product is in cart in magento-2.1 @Rose Hale.

Comment: Working.. Thanks @Rose Hale..

Comment: hi @Rose, same code i am using in controller, its not working for me, here is my question,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274172/quote-id-is-empty-when-inserting-multiple-records-into-cart-in-magento2

Answer (score 2):

A *before* plugin for the Quote class' AddProduct function might be a better way to do what you're trying to do.  From the [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/coding-standards/technical-guidelines.html#14-events), best practice is

> Events SHOULD NOT change a state of observable objects.

whereas a plugin

> is a class that modifies the behavior of public class functions by intercepting a function call and running code before, after, or around that function call. This allows you to substitute or extend the behavior of original, public methods for any class or interface.

Basically with a plugin you'd modify the price of the product before the quote object is created rather than changing the price of the quote object after it is created.

There's some good discussion about plugins vs observers and which is better. The general consensus seems to be that observers are a legacy Magento 1 thing whereas plugins are the new hotness, but both work.  You can read more of the discussion [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93932/magento-2-plugin-vs-observer) if you'd like.

Here's how you could do what you're after with a plugin.

Define the plugin in app/code/YourName/YourModule/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
    <plugin name="change_price_plugin" type="YourName\YourBuilder\Plugin\QuotePlugin"
            sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

Then in app/code/YourName/YourModule/Plugin/QuotePlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace YourName\YourModule\Plugin;

class QuotePlugin
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $subject
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param null|float|\Magento\Framework\DataObject $request
     * @param null|string $processMode
     * @throws \Exception
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeAddProduct(
        $subject,
        $product,
        $request = null,
        $processMode = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType::PROCESS_MODE_FULL
    ){          
        $newPrice = $product->getFinalPrice() + 10;
        $product->setPrice($newPrice);
        $request['custom_price'] = $newPrice;

        return [$product, $request, $processMode];
    }       
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a best aproach to the solution but do you know why it doesn't work for grouped products?

Comment: Any idea about how can i add product custom special price(Sale price) the same waay?

Answer (score 0):

public function execute(Observer $observer)  {

```
    /** @var $item \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */       $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();        if ($item) {
            foreach ($item->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $bundleitems) {
                /** @var $bundleitems\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
                //Skip the bundle product
                if ($bundleitems->getProduct()->getTypeId() == Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
                    continue;
                }
                $bundleitems->setCustomPrice(1.00);
                $bundleitems->setOriginalCustomPrice(1.00);
                $bundleitems->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

            }           }       return $this;   }
```