# Override AbstractPdf class in magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides

It is not good way to `override` `core` class of `Magento`. But I have to do this because I am in way that class is `abstract` and method is `protected` so I think `preference` and `plugin`should not work. I found couple of answers about [Override abstract class in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108001/override-abstract-class-in-magento-2) and [this one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91353/how-to-override-or-extend-protected-or-parent-function-in-magento-2-using-plugin) but both are not useful for me. So is there any other way to achieve this ? I want to override this class

`\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf`

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What i did

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice" type="Mycompany\Tax\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice" />
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Mycompany\Tax\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
```

and I copied the functions that i wanted to override of the abstract class in `app\code\Mycomany\Tax\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php`
like one thing i wanted to change was fonts

```
 /**
     * Set font as regular
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param  int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->getFontsDir() . ('dejavu-sans/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf')
        );
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }
    /**
     * Set font as bold
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param  int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    protected function _setFontBold($object, $size = 6)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->getFontsDir() . ('dejavu-sans/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf')
        );
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }

    /**
     * Set font as italic
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param  int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    protected function _setFontItalic($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->getFontsDir() . ('dejavu-sans/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf')
        );
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }
```

This is how i modified my **Insertorder**

```
 protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)
    {
        if ($obj instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order) {
            $shipment = null;
            $order = $obj;
        } elseif ($obj instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment) {
            $shipment = $obj;
            $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        }
        $sellerId=$order->getData('seller_id');
        $sellerInfo=$this->_taxHelper->getSellerAdressWithDetails($sellerId);
        $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
        $top = $this->y;

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 570, $top - 55);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $this->setDocHeaderCoordinates([25, $top, 570, $top - 55]);
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);

        if ($putOrderId) {
            $page->drawText(__('Order # ') . $order->getRealOrderId(), 35, $top -= 30, 'UTF-8');
        }
        $page->drawText(
            __('Order Date: ') .
            $this->_localeDate->formatDate(
                $this->_localeDate->scopeDate(
                    $order->getStore(),
                    $order->getCreatedAt(),
                    true
                ),
                \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
                false
            ),
            35,
            $top -= 15,
            'UTF-8'
        );
        $top -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 570, $top - 25);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
        $page->drawText(__('Sold By:'), 35, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top - 25, 570, $top - 33 - 80);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $this->y = $top - 40;
        $addressesStartY = $this->y;

        foreach(explode("\n", $sellerInfo) as $textLine){
            if ($textLine!=='') {
                $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                $this->y -=14;
            }
        }
        $addressesEndY = $this->y;

        $top -= 120;
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 275, $top - 25);
        $page->drawRectangle(275, $top, 570, $top - 25);

        /* Calculate blocks info */

        /* Billing Address */
        $billingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getBillingAddress(), 'pdf'));

        /* Payment */
        $paymentInfo = $this->_paymentData->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())->setIsSecureMode(true)->toPdf();
        $paymentInfo = htmlspecialchars_decode($paymentInfo, ENT_QUOTES);
        $payment = explode('{{pdf_row_separator}}', $paymentInfo);
        foreach ($payment as $key => $value) {
            if (strip_tags(trim($value)) == '') {
                unset($payment[$key]);
            }
        }
        reset($payment);

        /* Shipping Address and Method */
        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            /* Shipping Address */
            $shippingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getShippingAddress(), 'pdf'));
            $shippingMethod = $order->getShippingDescription();
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
        $page->drawText(__('Sold to:'), 35, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $page->drawText(__('Ship to:'), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        } else {
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method:'), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        }

        $addressesHeight = $this->_calcAddressHeight($billingAddress);
        if (isset($shippingAddress)) {
            $addressesHeight = max($addressesHeight, $this->_calcAddressHeight($shippingAddress));
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top - 25, 570, $top - 33 - $addressesHeight);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $this->y = $top - 40;
        $addressesStartY = $this->y;

        foreach ($billingAddress as $value) {
            if ($value !== '') {
                $text = [];
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $text[] = $_value;
                }
                foreach ($text as $part) {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                    $this->y -= 15;
                }
            }
        }

        $addressesEndY = $this->y;

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $this->y = $addressesStartY;
            foreach ($shippingAddress as $value) {
                if ($value !== '') {
                    $text = [];
                    foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                        $text[] = $_value;
                    }
                    foreach ($text as $part) {
                        $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                        $this->y -= 15;
                    }
                }
            }

            $addressesEndY = min($addressesEndY, $this->y);
            $this->y = $addressesEndY;

            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
            $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 275, $this->y - 25);
            $page->drawRectangle(275, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 25);

            $this->y -= 15;
            $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText(__('Shipping Method:'), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

            $this->y -= 10;
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));

            $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));

            $paymentLeft = 35;
            $yPayments = $this->y - 15;
        } else {
            $yPayments = $addressesStartY;
            $paymentLeft = 285;
        }

        foreach ($payment as $value) {
            if (trim($value) != '') {

                //Printing "Payment comments" lines
                $value = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>/i', "\n", $value);
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    if($_value=='No value')
                    {
                        $_value='No pay';
                    }
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), $paymentLeft, $yPayments, 'UTF-8');
                    $yPayments -= 15;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $yPayments = min($addressesEndY, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25, $top - 25, 25, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(570, $top - 25, 570, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25, $yPayments, 570, $yPayments);

            $this->y = $yPayments - 15;
        } else {
            $topMargin = 15;
            $methodStartY = $this->y;
            $this->y -= 15;

            foreach ($this->string->split($shippingMethod, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                $this->y -= 15;
            }

            $yShipments = $this->y;
            $totalShippingChargesText = "(" . __(
                    'Total Shipping Charges'
                ) . " " . $order->formatPriceTxt(
                    $order->getShippingAmount()
                ) . ")";

            $page->drawText($totalShippingChargesText, 285, $yShipments - $topMargin, 'UTF-8');
            $yShipments -= $topMargin + 10;

            $tracks = [];
            if ($shipment) {
                $tracks = $shipment->getAllTracks();
            }
            if (count($tracks)) {
                $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
                $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
                $page->drawRectangle(285, $yShipments, 510, $yShipments - 10);
                $page->drawLine(400, $yShipments, 400, $yShipments - 10);
                //$page->drawLine(510, $yShipments, 510, $yShipments - 10);

                $this->_setFontRegular($page, 9);
                $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
                //$page->drawText(__('Carrier'), 290, $yShipments - 7 , 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText(__('Title'), 290, $yShipments - 7, 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText(__('Number'), 410, $yShipments - 7, 'UTF-8');

                $yShipments -= 20;
                $this->_setFontRegular($page, 8);
                foreach ($tracks as $track) {
                    $maxTitleLen = 45;
                    $endOfTitle = strlen($track->getTitle()) > $maxTitleLen ? '...' : '';
                    $truncatedTitle = substr($track->getTitle(), 0, $maxTitleLen) . $endOfTitle;
                    $page->drawText($truncatedTitle, 292, $yShipments, 'UTF-8');
                    $page->drawText($track->getNumber(), 410, $yShipments, 'UTF-8');
                    $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
                }
            } else {
                $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
            }

            $currentY = min($yPayments, $yShipments);

            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $page->drawLine(25, $methodStartY, 25, $currentY);
            //left
            $page->drawLine(25, $currentY, 570, $currentY);
            //bottom
            $page->drawLine(570, $currentY, 570, $methodStartY);
            //right

            $this->y = $currentY;
            $this->y -= 15;
        }
    }
```

My approach was override the class that is using that method rather than abstract class

Comment: Thanks Vishwas for the some hints, but I think it is not useful to me actually I want to do some work on protected function insertOrder() , but still +1 from me for your efforts

Comment: @KeyurShah i have modified  insertOrder() as well added , added in my answer hope it helps

Comment: its in the same file Invoice.php , if you are trying to change it this might work , and if it not a best practice please do let me know @KeyurShah

Comment: you mean I have write something in di.xml like <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf" type="Mycompany\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf" /> . did you check that it's abstract class ? it will work ?Vishwas

Comment: no @KeyurShah  what I am saying rather than overriding the abstract class , override the class which calls that  insertOrder() method of abstract class . i overridden the  insertOrder() in my invoice.php file where it was used (i made some chnages for orders with zero payment )

Comment: let me check into this

Comment: if you check in invoice.php , getPdf() calls  $this->insertOrder . so when you override invoice.php and add your amended insertOrder () method in that only , that new amended method will be called rather than from abstract class . hope i have explained my self clearly @KeyurShah

Comment: Yes Thanks a lot Vishwas for your time and efforts , I will get back to you ASAP

Comment: Thanks Vishwas it's working fine for me :) I don't how miss that part ): Anyway bounty will credited after 24 hours

Comment: @KeyurShah, Have you overriden this file "\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not override AbstractPdf.php file.

Please check following link for more details.

[Click Here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/247822/magento2-remove-shipping-charge-and-credit-cart-type-and-number-from-order-inv/248583#248583)

Thanks.