# Magento2 : Remove shipping charge and credit cart type and number from order invoice

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice-pdf, abstract-class

I want to remove shipping charge and credit card type and credit card number from order invoice.

> [image: Blockquote]

please check image:

I have overridden this core file

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
>   this file working fine.

But while overridding this file

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php

I am not able to get any update of this file. I have commented some code from this file but not got any change.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating same methods which you want to override from AbstractPdf.php in your overided Invoice.php file. For example:

1) Create a preference for Invoice.php in di.xml

> `<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />`

2) In Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice, in you case create a method insertOrder

```
/**
 * Insert order to pdf page
 *
 * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page &$page
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $obj
 * @param bool $putOrderId
 * @return void
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)
{
    // comment relevent code according to your requirement
}
```

Comment: Please check my question i want to remove shipping taxes message and creditcard details.Thanks for reply

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check if you find it relevant

Comment: Okay let me check after i tell u

Comment: @PrachiSaxena, please check my updated answer.

Comment: @Sarfaraj, if this is working for you please accept my answer as the correct solution

Comment: @PrachiSaxena I need help please go through  "magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250625/… you have any idea reply me

Answer (score 1):

I have found this solution please check following file which i have been updated.

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepositoryFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice as InvoicePdf;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Invoice extends InvoicePdf
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryFactory
     */
    protected $productRepositoryFactory;
    protected $_logger;
    /**
     * Invoice constructor

     * @param Data $paymentData
     * @param StringUtils $string
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param Config $pdfConfig
     * @param Factory $pdfTotalFactory
     * @param ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory
     * @param TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param ResolverInterface $localeResolver
     * @param ProductRepositoryFactory $productRepositoryFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Data $paymentData,
        StringUtils $string,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        Config $pdfConfig,
        Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
        ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
        TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        Renderer $addressRenderer,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        ProductRepositoryFactory $productRepositoryFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, //log injection        
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $paymentData,
            $string,
            $scopeConfig,
            $filesystem,
            $pdfConfig,
            $pdfTotalFactory,
            $pdfItemsFactory,
            $localeDate,
            $inlineTranslation,
            $addressRenderer,
            $storeManager,
            $localeResolver,        
            $data
        );
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->productRepositoryFactory = $productRepositoryFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * Overridden in order to insert product image upon the order items rendering
     */
    public function getPdf($invoices = [])
    {
        $this->_logger->addInfo('getPdf sarfaraj');
        $this->_beforeGetPdf();
        $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

        $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
        $this->_setPdf($pdf);
        $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
                $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
            }
            $page = $this->newPage();           
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();
            /* Add image */
            $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add address */
            $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add head */
            $this->insertOrder(
                $page,
                $order,
                $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                    self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $order->getStoreId()
                )
            );
            /* Add document text and number */
            $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());
            /* Add table */
            $this->_drawHeader($page);
            /* Add body */
            foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                /* Draw item */
                $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);

                /* Insert the product image. You can play with position here */
                $this->insertImage($item, 140, (int)($this->y-15), 205, (int)($this->y+35), $page);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }
            /* Add totals */
            $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->revert();
            }
        }
        $this->_afterGetPdf();
        return $pdf;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * Overridden in order to change the order details background
     */
    protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)
    {
        $this->_logger->addInfo('insertOrder sarfaraj');
        if ($obj instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order) {
            $shipment = null;
            $order = $obj;
        } elseif ($obj instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment) {
            $shipment = $obj;
            $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        }

        $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
        $top = $this->y;

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1)); // Keep white color for the table header
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 570, $top - 55);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0)); // Make table header text white
        $this->setDocHeaderCoordinates([25, $top, 570, $top - 55]);
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);

        if ($putOrderId) {
            $page->drawText(__('Order # ') . $order->getRealOrderId(), 35, $top -= 30, 'UTF-8');
        }
        $page->drawText(
            __('Order Date: ') .
            $this->_localeDate->formatDate(
                $this->_localeDate->scopeDate(
                    $order->getStore(),
                    $order->getCreatedAt(),
                    true
                ),
                \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
                false
            ),
            35,
            $top -= 15,
            'UTF-8'
        );

        $top -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 275, $top - 25);
        $page->drawRectangle(275, $top, 570, $top - 25);

        /* Calculate blocks info */

        /* Billing Address */
        $billingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getBillingAddress(), 'pdf'));

        /* Payment */
        $paymentInfo = $this->_paymentData->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())->setIsSecureMode(true)->toPdf();
        $paymentInfo = htmlspecialchars_decode($paymentInfo, ENT_QUOTES);
        $payment = explode('{{pdf_row_separator}}', $paymentInfo);
        foreach ($payment as $key => $value) {
            if (strip_tags(trim($value)) == '') {
                unset($payment[$key]);
            }
        }
        reset($payment);

        /* Shipping Address and Method */
        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            /* Shipping Address */
            $shippingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getShippingAddress(), 'pdf'));
            $shippingMethod = $order->getShippingDescription();
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
        $page->drawText(__('Sold to: '), 35, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $page->drawText(__('Ship to: '), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        } else {
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method:'), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        }

        $addressesHeight = $this->_calcAddressHeight($billingAddress);
        if (isset($shippingAddress)) {
            $addressesHeight = max($addressesHeight, $this->_calcAddressHeight($shippingAddress));
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top - 25, 570, $top - 33 - $addressesHeight);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $this->y = $top - 40;
        $addressesStartY = $this->y;

        foreach ($billingAddress as $value) {
            if ($value !== '') {
                $text = [];
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $text[] = $_value;
                }
                foreach ($text as $part) {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                    $this->y -= 15;
                }
            }
        }

        $addressesEndY = $this->y;

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $this->y = $addressesStartY;
            foreach ($shippingAddress as $value) {
                if ($value !== '') {
                    $text = [];
                    foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                        $text[] = $_value;
                    }
                    foreach ($text as $part) {
                        $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                        $this->y -= 15;
                    }
                }
            }

            $addressesEndY = min($addressesEndY, $this->y);
            $this->y = $addressesEndY;

            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
            $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 275, $this->y - 25);
            $page->drawRectangle(275, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 25);

            $this->y -= 15;
            $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText(__('Shipping Method:'), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

            $this->y -= 10;
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));

            $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));

            $paymentLeft = 35;
            $yPayments = $this->y - 15;
        } else {
            $yPayments = $addressesStartY;
            $paymentLeft = 285;
        }

        foreach ($payment as $value) {
            if (trim($value) != '') {
                //Printing "Payment Method" lines
                $value = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>/i', "\n", $value);
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), $paymentLeft, $yPayments, 'UTF-8');
                    $yPayments -= 15;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $yPayments = min($addressesEndY, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25, $top - 25, 25, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(570, $top - 25, 570, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25, $yPayments, 570, $yPayments);

            $this->y = $yPayments - 15;
        } else {
            $topMargin = 15;
            $methodStartY = $this->y;
            $this->y -= 15;

            foreach ($this->string->split($shippingMethod, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                $this->y -= 15;
            }

            $yShipments = $this->y;
            $totalShippingChargesText = "(" . __(
                    'Total Shipping Charges '
                ) . " " . $order->formatPriceTxt(
                    $order->getShippingAmount()
                ) . ")";

            //$page->drawText($totalShippingChargesText, 285, $yShipments - $topMargin, 'UTF-8');
            $yShipments -= $topMargin + 10;

            $tracks = [];
            if ($shipment) {
                $tracks = $shipment->getAllTracks();
            }
            if (count($tracks)) {
                $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
                $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
                $page->drawRectangle(285, $yShipments, 510, $yShipments - 10);
                $page->drawLine(400, $yShipments, 400, $yShipments - 10);
                //$page->drawLine(510, $yShipments, 510, $yShipments - 10);

                $this->_setFontRegular($page, 9);
                $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
                //$page->drawText(__('Carrier'), 290, $yShipments - 7 , 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText(__('Title'), 290, $yShipments - 7, 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText(__('Number'), 410, $yShipments - 7, 'UTF-8');

                $yShipments -= 20;
                $this->_setFontRegular($page, 8);
                foreach ($tracks as $track) {
                    $maxTitleLen = 45;
                    $endOfTitle = strlen($track->getTitle()) > $maxTitleLen ? '...' : '';
                    $truncatedTitle = substr($track->getTitle(), 0, $maxTitleLen) . $endOfTitle;
                    $page->drawText($truncatedTitle, 292, $yShipments, 'UTF-8');
                    $page->drawText($track->getNumber(), 410, $yShipments, 'UTF-8');
                    $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
                }
            } else {
                $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
            }

            $currentY = min($yPayments, $yShipments);

            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $page->drawLine(25, $methodStartY, 25, $currentY);
            //left
            $page->drawLine(25, $currentY, 570, $currentY);
            //bottom
            $page->drawLine(570, $currentY, 570, $methodStartY);
            //right

            $this->y = $currentY;
            $this->y -= 15;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * Overridden in order to change the invoice ID text color
     */
    public function insertDocumentNumber(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page, $text)
    {
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0)); // Make table header text white
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $docHeader = $this->getDocHeaderCoordinates();
        $page->drawText($text, 35, $docHeader[1] - 15, 'UTF-8');
    }

    /**
     * Draws the product image using the specified coordinates
     *
     * @param DataObject $item
     * @param int $x1
     * @param int $y1
     * @param int $x2
     * @param int $y2
     * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page &$page
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function insertImage($item, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, \Zend_Pdf_Page &$page)
    {
        try{
            $product = $this->productRepositoryFactory->create()->getById($item->getProductId());
            $productImage = '/catalog/product' . $product->getData('thumbnail');
            $pdfImage = \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($productImage));

            //Draw image to PDF
            $page->drawImage($pdfImage, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }


    protected function insertLogo(&$page, $store = null)
    {
        $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
        $image = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'sales/identity/logo',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $store
        );
        if ($image) {
            $imagePath = '/sales/store/logo/' . $image;
            if ($this->_mediaDirectory->isFile($imagePath)) {
                $image = \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($imagePath));
                $top = 830;
                //top border of the page
                $widthLimit = 270;
                //half of the page width
                $heightLimit = 270;
                //assuming the image is not a "skyscraper"
                $width = $image->getPixelWidth();
                $height = $image->getPixelHeight();

                //preserving aspect ratio (proportions)
                $ratio = $width / $height;
                if ($ratio > 1 && $width > $widthLimit) {
                    $width = $widthLimit;
                    $height = $width / $ratio;
                } elseif ($ratio < 1 && $height > $heightLimit) {
                    $height = $heightLimit;
                    $width = $height * $ratio;
                } elseif ($ratio == 1 && $height > $heightLimit) {
                    $height = $heightLimit;
                    $width = $widthLimit;
                }

                $y1 = $top - $height;
                $y2 = $top;
                $x1 = 158;
                $x2 = $x1 + $width;

                //coordinates after transformation are rounded by Zend
                $page->drawImage($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);

                $this->y = $y1 - 10;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create new page and assign to PDF object
     *
     * @param  array $settings
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Page
     */
    public function newPage(array $settings = [])
    {
        /* Add new table head */
        $page = $this->_getPdf()->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $this->_getPdf()->pages[] = $page;
        $this->y = 800;
        if (!empty($settings['table_header'])) {
            $this->_drawHeader($page);
        }
        return $page;
    }

}
```

In this file i have added AbstractPdf.php file insertOrder() method  and modify changes so now it is working for me.

For more details please try this module you will answer.

[Click Here...](https://github.com/sarfaraj-php/M2-Invoice-PDF-Modification)

Thanks.

Comment: Hello @sarfaraj, 
As you have done modification in this invoice class with Protected function, lets assume some changes in this protected function insertImage(), so how to write PHPUnit for this class?
Any help would be appreciated!!