# overwriting the AbstractPdf.php

Tags: magento2.3.1, pdf

I am trying to overwrite the core **AbstractPdf.php** from

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/order/PDF/AbstractPdf.php
```

**To**

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/projecta/Magento_Sales/Model/order/PDF/AbstractPdf.php
```

I did flush the cache after, but seems still using the core file, am I missing something? do I need to run some script to make this override works? I did search from any where over the internet, still not clear when I should do. Please help

Thanks!

Comment: you can't override any php file inside design folder. for that you need to creare di.xml file under module and then override it

Comment: Do I need to run magento command to make it works, if I have the di.xml wrote up?

Comment: yes you need tu run di:compile command for that

Answer (score 3):

You can not override any php file in your theme. Required to create di.xml file in etc folder of your module.

[Check answered how to override.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153308/override-abstractpdf-class-in-magento2/154428)

Comment: someone said it is protected function, so I cannot override, is that true? so create a custom model with di.xml can solve the problem?