# Magento 2 - override private method in abstract class

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin, abstract-class

Is there a way to override a private method of an abstract class in magento 2?

I need to override the **private** method `correctText` of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf`

Comment: I think you can find the solution in this question from a while ago
[Override AbstractPdf class in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/153308/104013)