# Overriding Magento 2.3 Checkout Cart Control Using Plugin using around but not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cart, addtocart, around-plugin

What I am trying to achieve is when a product is added to the cart, the customer will have the option to add a special gift box. As every product has a different gift box and price so to do this what I did is added product id of gift box into input type hidden fields on product view page and when user is clicking on add to cart, I can have the gift box id in additional option in params of the cart. and by using that gift box id, I can add the giftbox product to cart as well.

I tried using the plugin, but it is not working. can anyone help me to see what is wrong?

Here is my di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add">
        <plugin name="SamaaAdditionCart" type="Samaa\AdditionalCart\Plugin\AddPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

AND here is my AddPlugin.php

```
namespace Samaa\AdditionalCart\Plugin;

class AddPlugin
{        
    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {

        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('Your session has expired')
            );
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();




        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get(
                        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface::class
                    )->getLocale()]
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            if (!$product) {
                return $this->goBack();
            }

            if(isset($params['options']))
            {
                if(isset($params['options']['additional_product_option']));
                {
                    $addition_product_id = $params['options']['additional_product_option'];
                    if(is_numeric($addition_product_id) && $addition_product_id!="")
                    {

                            $storeId = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class)->getStore()->getId();  
                            $giftBoxproduct = $this->productRepository->getById($addition_product_id, false, $storeId);
                            $giftBoxProductParameters = array('product' => $addition_product_id,
                                'qty' => $params['qty'],
                                 'form_key' => $params['form_key']
                            );  
                            $this->cart->addProduct($giftBoxproduct, $giftBoxProductParameters);
                            unset($params['options']['additional_product_option']);
                    }

                }
            } 


            $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }

            $this->cart->save();

            /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer \Magento\Wishlist\Observer\AddToCart
             */
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
            );

            if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                if (!$this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                    if ($this->shouldRedirectToCart()) {
                        $message = __(
                            'You added %1 to your shopping cart.',
                            $product->getName()
                        );
                        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
                    } else {
                        $this->messageManager->addComplexSuccessMessage(
                            'addCartSuccessMessage',
                            [
                                'product_name' => $product->getName(),
                                'cart_url' => $this->getCartUrl(),
                            ]
                        );
                    }
                }
                return $this->goBack(null, $product);
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($this->_checkoutSession->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(
                    $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class)->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                );
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class)->escapeHtml($message)
                    );
                }
            }

            $url = $this->_checkoutSession->getRedirectUrl(true);

            if (!$url) {
                $url = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($this->getCartUrl());
            }

            return $this->goBack($url);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                $e,
                __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
            );
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            return $this->goBack();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: showing any error ???

Comment: i think use this line ---  `<plugin name="Samaa_AdditionalCart_addPlugin" type="Samaa\AdditionalCart\Plugin\AddPlugin" sortOrder="1" />`

Comment: Hi @MohitPatel No error no logs

Comment: I have above add new line try...

Comment: @MohitPatel Tried the same but not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to tried with Over ride controller for such functionality rather then create Plugin on that.
use preference of that controller and do your custom code with each Product add to cart that easily you can manager and also handle it.

Let me know if you have still query.

Thanks

Comment: As I know, Add.php in the cart controller is an abstract controller, which means override won't work.@Nirav Gohel